# What is the best way to implement self-referenced one-to-many relationships in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I want to implement a follower following relationship in Grails GORM. One implementation could be:

```
class User {
  String name
}

class Follower {
  User user 
  User follower
}
```

OR:

```
class User {
  String name

  static hasMany = [follower: User, following: User]
}
```

What is the best way to implement that a user can have many follower and a user can follow many users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class User {
  String name

static hasMany = [follower: User, following: User]
}

this will be better because you can easily create instance of new follower and then can easily to addTo method to add it as hasmany